# meaning of `button_map` in the form_field definition in flask-bootstrap

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-bootstrap

I am reading the documentation of [flask-boostrap doc](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/forms.html). In the `form_field` definition, what is the purpose of the `button_map`?

```
form_field(field, form_type="basic", horizontal_columns=('lg', 2, 10), button_map={})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your link (see [`quick_form`](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Bootstrap/forms.html#quick_form)):

> **button_map** – A dictionary, mapping button field names to names such as `primary`, `danger` or `success`. Buttons not found in the `button_map` will use the `default` type of button.

That means if you did something like

```
form_field(submit_button, button_map={'submit_button': 'primary'})
```

you'd get a button with `primary` as its type.

As the docs also mention, `form_field` is used primarily by `quick_form` where a mapping makes more sense than for an individual field.

Answer (score 3):

If you render form as a quick_form then 'btn-primary' class will be added to 'submit' button.

```
{{ wtf.quick_form(form, button_map={'submit': 'primary'}) }}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the above two answers, whatever name you use to call your SubmitField (ie. submit button) when you create your Flask form, is the same name you use inside the map
eg

##WTForm

```
class CreatePostForm(FlaskForm):

 #some code here

    submit_button = SubmitField("Submit Post")
```

Your quick form will be:

```
 {{wtf.quick_form(form, novalidate=True, button_map = {"submit_button":"primary"} )}}
```